# Sending raw xml string directly into a soap service with java

Tags: java, soap

Is it possible to send an xml string directly into the soap serivce instead of generating the java classes for it?

We want to send in this xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ver="http://www.timeedit.se/timeedit3/version2">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <ver:findObjects>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ver:login>
        <username>xxxxxxxx</username>
        <password>xxxxxxxx</password>
        <applicationkey>xxxxxxxxx</applicationkey>
     </ver:login>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ver:type>t_hel_programtillfälle</ver:type>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ver:exactsearchfields>
        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
        <field>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <extid>f_start_slut_termin</extid>
           <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
           <value>h11</value>
        </field>
        <field>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <extid>f_start_slut_termin</extid>
           <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
           <value>v14</value>
        </field>
        <field>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <extid>f_anmälningskod</extid>
           <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
           <value>10001</value>
        </field>
    </ver:exactsearchfields>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ver:generalsearchstring></ver:generalsearchstring>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ver:active>true</ver:active>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ver:reserved>true</ver:reserved>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ver:sortorder>?</ver:sortorder>
     <ver:beginindex>0</ver:beginindex>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ver:numberofobjects>20</ver:numberofobjects>
  </ver:findObjects>
```

Comment: You can HTTP post whatever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an HTTPURLConnection.  See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getOutputStream()

Comment: Page is no longer available

Answer (score 2):

I had done a similar thing using Spring Web Service (http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/). In the Spring @Endpoint method you can use the xml String but convert it to one of the valid type, e.g. javax.xml.transform.Source (see http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/server.html#d4e1220).